# How do I get MS Powerpoint to display italicised Cyrillic text in Serbian Cursive style?

Tags: localization, powerpoint, ms-office, typography

For me, PowerPoint only displays in Russian cursive style as follows:

[image: 2]

but I want it to look like this instead:

[image: 1]